# Why is $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + \Theta(x)$ for $x \in (0,1)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I am trying to understand the statement
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + \Theta(x)
$$
for $0 < x < 1$.

To my understanding, this could mean two things:

1. There are constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that $1+C_1 x \leq \frac{1}{1-x} \leq 1 + C_2 x$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. However, this is false as such a $C_2$ does not exist.
2. There exist constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that $1 + C_1x \leq \frac{1}{1-x} \leq 1 + C_2x$ for all large (or small) enough $x$. However, this is not a statement about $x$, so in that case I cannot make sense of the "for $0<x<1$"  part.

So how should this statement be interpreted? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong, $\frac1{1-x}=1+f(x)$ with $f(x)\gg x$ when $x\to1$.

Comment: Heh :-| ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: No, the statement holds in $(0,\alpha)$ with $\alpha<1$, but in $(0,1)$ the function is just unbounded.